# I need a tag control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

Everyone who is reading this question must be aware of how stackoverflow lets you add tags to questions.

I am building an application which lets user select multiple options from a multi-selection as follow

```
<select multiple="multiple">
about 200 options are present here
</select>
```

It is very difficult to use that list for about 200 options as space for vertical scroll is only about 100 px.

Does anybody know a ready-made control like stack overflow tag.

Note: The user should not be able to add his own options.

---

**If not control, then any suggestion is welcome on how I should display 200 options to the user in a user friendly way.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make use of any auto complete controls - [control from Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) for the one - and manually validate user's input to allow only existing options to be entered. The control from toolkit gives a lot of UI customization options, and you can set up any completion list markup.